# How to Add Vertical Scrollbar to a Specific ul > li in the Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

How do I target a specific `ul > li` element in a drop-down menu? The caveat is that I cannot edit the HTML (nav items) directly, it's generated automatically by the tool I use. However, I can manipulate the CSS, to some extent. So, I was wondering if there is a way to target a specific `ul > li` element to add a vertical scrollbar.

I need to target `ul > li` of **Sub Menu 3**, as illustrated in the code below. Note that those classes are automatically generated by the tool. I tried using the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class, but I think I am not doing it right.

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="children"><a href="#">Main Menu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="children"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="children"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li class="children" data-mc-id="11"><a href="">**Sub Menu 3**</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `>` to go down the DOM and select the nth-menu each time using `nth-of-type()` to select the right one.

The scrollbar can be added be constraining the height to a maximum and adding `overflow-y:auto` to add a scroll bar if the content of the element is higher.

To select the nth element in an `<ul>` just do the same but specify the nth type of `li` instead.

```css
.sub-menu>li>.sub-menu:nth-of-type(1) {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 10em;
}

.sub-menu>li>.sub-menu:nth-of-type(1)>li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="children"><a href="#">Main Menu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="children"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="children"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li class="children" data-mc-id="11"><a href="">**Sub Menu 3**</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastian Speitel. This was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If this is your HTML output you can target this element `<li class="children" data-mc-id="11">` and go from there.

Example:

```css
li[data-mc-id] ul.sub-menu {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
}

li[data-mc-id] ul.sub-menu li{
    background-color: red
}
    
li[data-mc-id] ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(3){
    background-color: green
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="children"><a href="#">Main Menu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="children"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="children"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li class="children" data-mc-id="11"><a href="">**Sub Menu 3**</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
          <li class="children"><a href="">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Kiss. The data-mc-id is generated automatically and the id changes on each build.

Comment: @RCB No problem, you can still select it like this `li[data-mc-id]`, I've changed my examples